# "Error: Node is either not clickable or not an HTMLElement" Puppeteer when i tried to get input by name

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, puppeteer, node-red

This is my HTML structure:

```
<div id="divImporte">
  <p class="btn01">
    <input type="button" name="Enviar Tasas" value="Enviar Tasas">
  </p>
</div>
```

And this is the ways how i try to select the input:

first way:

```
const buttonTasas = await page.$$("input[type='button'][value='Enviar Tasas']");
```

second way:

```
const buttonTasas = await page.waitForSelector("input[type='button'][value='Enviar Tasas']");
```

and then click it:

```
if (buttonTasas && buttonTasas.length > 0) {
  await buttonTasas[0].click();
}
```

i got this error:

```
"Error: Node is either not clickable or not an HTMLElement"
```

How can i solve? thanks

Comment: Be careful as your "1st way" returns an array whereas `2nd way` doesn't, otherwise this looks correct.  try adding  `{visible: true}` as a 2nd parameter of `waitForSelector` to be sure it waits for the element to be visible, and try adding some small delay before clicking the element with `await page.waitForTimeout(1000)` just to make sure the element is loaded

Comment: Hi @lezhumain i tried to use timeout and {visible: true} as second param but i got the same error. When i use node.warn into buttonTasas i got this: `JSHandle@node`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sometimes `puppeteer` just fails to click for some reason, so after double checking that `buttonTasas` is not null and trying to add some delay just before calling the `click()` method, you can try the following workaround to call the click function directly in the page:

With `page.evaluate` (https://pptr.dev/api/puppeteer.page.evaluate):

```js
page.evaluate((btnSelector) => {
    // this executes in the page
    document.querySelector(btnSelector).click();
}, "input[type='button'][value='Enviar Tasas']");
```

or maybe can you use the element directly:

```js
page.evaluate((btn) => {
    // this executes in the page
    btn.click();
}, buttonTasas);
```

With `page.$eval` (https://pptr.dev/api/puppeteer.page._eval):

```js
await page.$eval(
  'input[type='button'][value='Enviar Tasas']',
  (el) => {
    el.click()
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

UI tools for browsers usually have issues with white spaces. Try to search an element using an expression without any spaces or new lines. You can find a word inside a string using `*=` in CSS expressions:

```
await page.$$("input[type='button'][value*='Enviar']");
```

or

```
await page.$$("input[type='button'][value*='Enviar'][value*='Tasas']");
```